# Проблема с OptionTree

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

При натяжке проекта на WP, использовал плагин OptionTree. Все настроено, все работает. Но при переносе на другой сервер , на месте блоков, в которых отображается контент из настроек плагина, просто висит текст ошибки. Сколько не копался в этом - решить не смог. Может кто подскажет, что не так?(и да, все переменные и значения для foreach 100 раз перепроверил)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переносить надо ТОЛЬКО плагином Duplicator. У вас, похоже, все сериализованные данные в базе поломались.

Comment: Попробую перенести с его помощью

Comment: И правда, все вышло! Спасибо

Comment: добавлю к вышесказанному. И не использовать мутные решения, да ещё и засохшие как экскременты мамонта https://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/

Comment: @SeVlad ты не поверишь, я с этим Options Tree долбался в относительно свежей теме. Непонятно зачем его   в тему воткнули вообще

Comment: @KAGGDesign а "свежая" тема небось с темофореса, угу?

Comment: @SeVlad оттуда. Заказчик притащил)

Comment: @KAGGDesign :) Я не удивлён. С некоторых пор я говорю что это [помойка](https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9/#post-242932). Только платная.